# show all comment answers from database

Tags: php, sql

By using this model I wrote, I can only get an answer from the database for each comment.

Now I want to show all the answers for a comment What should I do?

**post model**

```
<?php

class Model_post extends Model
{
    function postComment($url)
    {
        $sql = "select * from tbl_postcomment where posttitle=? and parent=0";
        $result = $this->doSelect($sql, [$url]);
        $sql = "select * from tbl_postcomment where parent!=0";
        $all_answers = $this->doSelect($sql);
        $all_answer_new = [];
        foreach ($all_answers as $answer) {
            $question_id = $answer['parent'];
            $all_answer_new[$question_id] = $answer;
        }
        return [$result, $all_answer_new];
    }
}

?>
```

**post controller**

```
<?php

class Post extends Controller
{
   function id($url)
    {
        $postComment = $this->model->postComment($url);
        $qestions=$postComment[0];
        $answers=$postComment[1];
        $data = [$qestions,$answers];
        $this->view('post/index', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If you expect each question to have multiple answers you probably want `$all_answer_new[$question_id][] = $answer;`.   Building up an array of answers rather than overwriting the previous.

Comment: just replace `$all_answer_new[$question_id] = $answer;` to  `$all_answer_new[$question_id][] = $answer;` ? pls help for coding!

Answer (score 0):

The `$question_id` has the same value in your loops over the answers of a question. Your code overwrites the previous answers. And it's normal that you can see only one answer per question.

Try to append the answers to `$all_answer_new[$question_id]` (Which is an array by itself. `$all_answer_new` is a two-dimensional array that holds all answers of all of questions.)

Replace `$all_answer_new[$question_id] = $answer;` with something like this:

```
if (empty($all_answer_new[$question_id])) {
  $all_answer_new[$question_id] = array();
}
$all_answer_new[$question_id][] = $answer;
```